# Foreign key relation ship between two databases in SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have two databases, is it possible to create a foreign key between two tables in different databases in SQL Server 2008?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx):

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint can reference columns in tables in the same
>   database or within the same table.

So, you can not create foreign key constraints between two tables in different databases.

This is one of disadvantages of using multiple databases.

Comment: In addition, you can set up a procedure in one or both databases, in which you would pass the required insert operation information, and have it check to see if the "foreign key" exists in the other database.  But I would probably consider reworking your databases into one.

Comment: @DalinSeivewright Dalin what about Linked Servers. Are they of some use in this case

Comment: @Kamal I've never actually used Linked Servers before so I had no advice about them.  It would probably be more of a "Best Practices" approach though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linq2Sql or the entity framework - You can do it in the designer.

But as Igor say - in the DB itself you cant do it.